# BeautifulSoup findAll function multi attributes select not working at the right way

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This my source code I really try to get all green and red spans but actually I get the green one only!

any idea about that ?

python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3


from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.error   import HTTPError,URLError
from bs4            import BeautifulSoup
import re
import sys


def main():
    src = urlopen('http://www.pythonscraping.com/pages/warandpeace.html')
    txt = src.read()
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(txt)
    spans = bsObj.findAll('span',{'class':'red','class':'green'},recursive=True)
    outfile = '''
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>


    '''
    for span in spans:
        outfile = outfile + str(span)
    outfile = outfile + '</body></html>'
    print(outfile)

main()
```

Thanks all, Sherby

Comment: Dictionaries in python require unique keys. `{'class':'red','class':'green'}` would actually be equivalent to `{'class':'green'}` because the key 'class' is being overridden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change this line:

```
spans = bsObj.findAll('span',{'class':'red','class':'green'},recursive=True)
```

to :

```
spans = bsObj.findAll('span',{'class':['red','green']},recursive=True)
```